Block WebRTC for specific sites in Chrome selenium c#
I have chrome extension to block WebRTC. I need to allow WebRTC on some sites. I tried bypass list and add UrlFilter url:// but none of these work. Any one knows how to do it?
here is the manifest.json:
I have chrome extension to block WebRTC. I need to allow WebRTC on some sites. I tried bypass list and add UrlFilter url:// but none of these work. Any one knows how to do it?
here is the manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Block WebRTC Features",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Blocks WebRTC features, disables non-proxied UDP",
  "permissions": ["proxy", "declarativeNetRequest"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}

and background.js:
    chrome.proxy.settings.set(
    { value: { mode: "fixed_servers", rules: { bypassList: [] } }, scope: "regular" },
        () => console.log("Proxy settings applied.")
    );
    
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        addRules: [
            {
                id: 1,
                priority: 1,
                action: { type: "block" },
                condition: { urlFilter: "*", resourceTypes: ["xmlhttprequest"] }
            }
        ],
        removeRuleIds: [1]
    });

and content.js:
    // Block WebRTC support detection
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'RTCPeerConnection', {
        get: () => {
            console.log("Blocked RTCPeerConnection");
            return undefined;
        }
    });
    
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'RTCSessionDescription', {
        get: () => {
            console.log("Blocked RTCSessionDescription");
            return undefined;
        }
    });
    
    // Block access to navigator.mediaDevices
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
        get: () => {
            console.log("Blocked navigator.mediaDevices");
            return undefined;
        }
    });
    
    // Block other WebRTC objects if necessary
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'MediaStream', {
        get: () => {
            console.log("Blocked MediaStream");
            return undefined;
        }
    });

Thank you!

Add "world": "MAIN", "run_at": "document_start" to content_scripts declaration.
